# What kind of edge do we have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

In order to find the kind of the edges of a graph, at which we applied the Depth-first search algorithm, we could use this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\text{ tree edges: } x \to y & [d[y],f[y]] \subset [d[x],f[x]] \\ \\
\text{forward edges: } x \to y & [d[x],f[x]] \subset [d[y],f[y]] \\ \\
\text{back edges: } x \to y    & [d[y],f[y]] \subset [d[x],f[x]] \\ \\
\text{Cross edges: } x \to y   & [d[x],f[x]] \cap [d[y],f[y]]=\varnothing
\end{bmatrix}$$

But, when we have for example the case $[d[y],f[y]] \subset [d[x],f[x]]$ how can we know if it is a tree  edge or a back edge?

**EDIT**:

*Discovery Time*: The discovery time $d[v]$ is the number of nodes discovered or finished before first seeing $v$.

*Finishing Time*: The finishing time $f[v]$ is the number of nodes discovered or finished before finishing the expansion of $v$.

That's the graph I am looking at:

[image]

And here are the discovery and finish times I found:

[image]

**EDIT**: Algorithm:

```
Depthfirstsearch(G)
   for each v ∈ V
        color[v]=white
        p[v]=NIL
   time=0
   for each v ∈ V
       if color[v]=white then
          Visit(v)


Visit(u)
  color[u]=gray
  time=time+1
  d[u]=time
  for each v ∈ Adj[u]
       if color[v]=white then
          p[v]=u
          Visit(v)
  color[u]=black
  time=time+1
  f[u]=time
```

**EDIT**:

At the beginning the colours that the nodes get, are the following:

[image]

At which step do we look at the colors that the nodes got in order to check the type of the edges?

**EDIT**:

[image]

Comment: What does $[d[a],f[b]] means?

Comment: @Phicar It's the interval [discovery time, finish time].

Comment: @Phicar I edited my post and added more information about $d[v]$ and $f[v]$.

Comment: I saw, thanks! A back edge must have $y$ visited and a tree edge must not have $y$ visited. In the DFS you can take account of what vertices have you visited.

Comment: @Phicar I edited my post..Could you have a look at it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An edge $x \to y$ is a tree edge iff $y$ was first discovered when DFS traversed the edge $x \to y$. If we only have access to the discovery and finishing times (and we can't just modify the DFS algorithm), then an equivalent condition is that $x \to y$ is a tree edge iff for any other vertex $z \neq y$, we have that:
$$
[d[z], f[z]] \subset [d[x], f[x]] \implies [d[z], f[z]] \subset [d[y], f[y]] \subset [d[x], f[x]]
$$
In other words, $[d[y], f[y]]$ is the largest possible proper subset of $[d[x], f[x]]$.

Comment: I added the graph I am looking at.. So are the types of the edges the following? Or have I done something wrong?
$$\\ a-c: \text{ back edge } \\c-f: \text{ tree edge }\\c-g: \text{tree edge}\\a-g: \text{ back edge}\\a-d: \text{ tree edge}\\d-h: \text{ back edge}\\d-i: \text{ back edge}\\h-j: \text{ tree edge}\\b-i: \text{ tree edge}\\b-e: \text{tree edge}\\e-i: \text{ cross edge}\\i-a: \text{ back edge}\\j-h: \text{ forward edge}  $$

Comment: You should have:
\begin{align*}
\text{Tree Edges:}&~~~ ac, cf, cg, ad, dh, hj, di, be \\
\text{Forward Edges:}&~~~ ag \\
\text{Back Edges:}&~~~ jh, ia \\
\text{Cross Edges:}&~~~ bi, ei
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you explain me why $ac$ is a tree edge?
$$$$
I thought that it isn't because $[2,7]$ contains $6$ numbers, while $[8,15]$ contains $8$ numbers.
$$$$
So am I wrong?

Comment: Since $[2, 7]$ is a subset of $[1, 16]$, we know that $ac$ is either a tree edge or a forward edge. It must be a tree edge because $c$ was first discovered when DFS traversed the edge $ac$.

Comment: So,  if we have $[d[y],f[y]] \subset [d[x],f[x]]$ , doesn't it hold that the corresponding edge is a tree edge only if $[d[y],f[y]]$ is the subset which contains the greatest number of numbers?

Comment: Could you explain me further how we can if is is a tree edge or not? I haven't really understood it..

Comment: Imagine performing DFS. Initially, all edges and vertices are coloured blue. Now each time you discover a vertex $v$ that you've never seen before (that is, it's coloured blue), colour the edge from the parent vertex $u$ to the new vertex $v$ with a red marker (while you're at it, colour both $u$ and $v$ red, to keep track that you've now visited them both). At the end, you'll have a red forest (a collection of red trees), where each red edge is a tree edge).

Comment: Adriano I edited my post.. Could you explain me at which step we look at the colours that the nodes got in order to see what type of edge we have?

Comment: In the `Visit(u)` method (within the `for` loop and `if` condition), there is the assignment statement `p[v] = u`, meaning that in the tree, the parent of $v$ is $u$. This tells us that $uv$ is a tree edge.

Comment: The exercise I am looking at asks me to show  how depth-first search works on a graph. So do I have to write the commands that are executed or do I have just to write at the nodes the discovery and finishing times and  add the red arrows at the graph?